# A que se deberá este error en windows forms c# al llamar un método para generar una carta en office

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010100): No se pudo
>   recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID
>   {00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} debido al siguiente error:
>   80010100 Error en la llamada de sistema. (Excepción de HRESULT:
>   0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)).    en
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType
>   objectType)    en
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   serverType)    en
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType
>   serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)

A continuación les dejo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
                var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();


                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field field in document.Fields)
                {
                    if (field.Code.Text.Contains("NOMEPL"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(NOMEPL);
                    }
                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("APEEPL"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(APEEPL);
                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("VLRAPR"))
                    {

                        field.Select();
                        double VLR_APR = Convert.ToDouble(VLRAPR);
                        application.Selection.TypeText(VLR_APR.ToString("#,##0.00"));

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("CARGO"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(NOMCAR);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("NOMPRO"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(NOMPRO);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("DEPENDENCIA"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(DEPENDENCIA);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("NomFirma"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(NombreFirma);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("CargoFirma"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(CargoFirma);

                    }


                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("dependenciaFirma"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(dependenciaFirma);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("ExtFirma"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(ExtFirma);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("fec_generacion"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        string FechaActual = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); ;
                        application.Selection.TypeText(FechaActual);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("DIA_FEC_GENERACION"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        string Dia = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
                        application.Selection.TypeText(Dia);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("MES_FEC_GENERACION"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        string Mes = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
                        ObtenerNombreMes(Mes);
                        application.Selection.TypeText(NombreGenericoMes);

                    }

                    else if (field.Code.Text.Contains("ANIO_FEC_GENERACION"))
                    {
                        field.Select();
                        string Anio = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

                        application.Selection.TypeText(Anio);

                    }


                }

                if (directorio == "")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    if (plantillaencontrada == true)
                    {
                        document.SaveAs2(FileName: @"" + directorio + "" + "\\" + "Preadjudicacion_" + APEEPL + " " + NOMEPL + ".docx");


                        document.Close();
                        application.Quit();

                        MessageBox.Show("Se ha Generado la Carta de PreadJudicación para el Trabajador " + APEEPL + "" + NOMEPL + "  En la Carpeta +" + directorio, "Información", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        break;
                    }

                    break;

                }


            }
```

Comment: Brother, bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero que coloques todo el código que has utilizado para poder ayudarte, caso contrario, es muy complicado tratar de resolverlo. Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

Hace referencia a que no puede crear la instancia del `objeto COM de office`, recuerda que las dll del office no son .net sino que fueron creadas con `VB6`, por eso son `COM`.

Debes tener instalado `Ms Office` en la misma version he idioma co la cual desarrollaste para que se pueda crear la instancia.

Es por eso que se recomiendo usar librerias basadas en `open xml` para desarrollar.

[Bienvenido a SDK de Open XML 2.5 para Office](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)

Puede que resulte algo mas complicado, pero son las librerias que recomendarias aprendas a usar y no las `Interop de office`

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, no vino de un tema de código sino de un tema propio de Windows:

1. No tienes windows con la licencia activada.
2. No estas logueado con una cuenta con licencia en el office del servidor donde se corre la webapp.
3. La cuenta de office licenciada que se usa, está presente en más de 5 dispositivos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).